# How to handle connection loss using .NET SqlDependency

Tags: c#, .net, sqldependency

I need to register SqlDependency to watch new data on remote SQL Server (2005). Connection loss is probable, because connections are across cities and countries. How should I to handle connection loss? In normal mode I can use exception on .Open(), but using SqlDependency connection is still opened.

Thank you for your tips.

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT id FROM dbo.batches WHERE terminalId = @terminalId", msConnection);

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@terminalId", SqlDbType.Int);
command.Parameters["@terminalId"].Value = terminalId;

SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(NewBatchHandler);
SqlDependency.Start(connectionString);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an overloaded constructor to decrease the timeout, at least reducing the frequency of this issue. This is an issue MS knows about, and unfortunately has no fix I am aware of.

Microsoft party line is they know it's an issue and aren't going to fix it. In the past, I have rolled my own solutions based on polling when this became a real issue with a production database.

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/543921/sqldependency-incorrect-behaviour-after-sql-server-restarts

Comment: Thank for info. What about repetitive reconnection/reinitialization by timer, for example (as prevention)?

Comment: @Fanda What approach did you end up taking in your application?

Comment: I decide to not use SqlDependency. But solution I was thinking about was to combine it with polling/reconnectig in some time period.